# How can I cook meat quickly without pressure cooker?

Tags: meat, pressure-cooker

When I cook beef or mutton without a pressure cooker, it takes a long time for it to cook properly. Are there any methods of cooking meat quickly without using a pressure cooker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cooking time is dependent, amongst other things, on the thickness of the meat. Small cubes of meat will be cooked much faster than huge slabs. Look up 'minute steak'.

Comment: or you could just pound it till it gets thin...